This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I learn mobile application development 1 weeks before and stuck with error below.
I just follow the simple tutorial to create project in https://reactnative.dev/ dan https://docs.expo.dev/ and still get same error.
Things that i done to overcome this issue and doing this over and over and still give me same issue:

Delete .node_modules and .expo folder and install package again
Clear cache npm and install package again
Check proxy and make sure no proxy configured
Use different wifi to install package
Downgrade node.js to v18 Long support and install npm again
open with debug mode and got error with metro bundle stop work

The strange thing is clone this project in my another device and install package then the project doing fine, after open in web and my phone with expo QR.
Repo : https://github.com/nonefornothing/LevelUp-FE


Error when open debug mode in expo

Any suggestion will be appreciate,
Thanks

I also shutdown wsl and its still same

tried to clear network cache still not work
